# Reading .xlsx in java through apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, xmlbeans

I'm trying to read data from .xlsx file into my java program. I'm able to read .xls but when i try the same code with .xlsx i get exception.

Code to access file :

```
FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fs);
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
```

exception trace:

```
> org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:62)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:465)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:173)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:248)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:209)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:168)
    at com.sap.bo.st.utilities.ReadInputs.getAllInputs(ReadInputs.java:21)
    at testplan.job.JobCount.createData1(JobCount.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:136)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:430)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleParameters(Invoker.java:1287)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.createParameters(Invoker.java:1004)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1093)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:771)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:621)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:357)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:352)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:310)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:259)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1176)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1101)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1009)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:60)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.typeSystemForClassLoader(XmlBeans.java:768)
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.ThemeDocument.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.ThemeDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ThemesTable.<init>(ThemesTable.java:83)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not instantiate SchemaTypeSystemImpl (java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException): is the version of xbean.jar correct?
    at schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sE130CAA0A01A7CDE5A2B4FEB8B311707.TypeSystemHolder.loadTypeSystem(Unknown Source)
    at schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sE130CAA0A01A7CDE5A2B4FEB8B311707.TypeSystemHolder.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: org.apache.xmlbeans.SchemaTypeLoaderException: XML-BEANS compiled schema: Incompatible minor version - expecting up to 23, got 24 (schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sE130CAA0A01A7CDE5A2B4FEB8B311707.index) - code 3
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemImpl$XsbReader.<init>(SchemaTypeSystemImpl.java:1520)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemImpl.initFromHeader(SchemaTypeSystemImpl.java:260)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemImpl.<init>(SchemaTypeSystemImpl.java:183)
    ... 54 more
```

I've tried updating the XMLbeans.jar to the latest version but still I'm getting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
//Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fs);
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
```

If using maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Or jars that I use:

```
commons-codec-1.9.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
junit-4.12.jar
log4j-1.2.17.jar
poi-3.13-20150929.jar
poi-examples-3.13-20150929.jar
poi-excelant-3.13-20150929.jar
poi-ooxml-3.13-20150929.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.13-20150929.jar
poi-scratchpad-3.13-20150929.jar
xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar
```

If still error, please create another new xlsx file to test

Comment: getting same exception trace with this as well. Already tried

Comment: XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);                            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

Comment: do you use maven? please add the content of pom.xml

Comment: So which jar do you include in the project?

Comment: jars available in poi-3.13

Comment: Please check the jars which I use in my answer, I run without error

Comment: I was using the same jars as you mentioned but different versions, i updated the versions to what you have specified but still getting the same exception. I will test with another .xlsx file and let you know.

Answer (score 2):

The key bit of your exception is near the end:

```
Caused by: org.apache.xmlbeans.SchemaTypeLoaderException: XML-BEANS compiled schema: 
Incompatible minor version - expecting up to 23, got 24 (schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sE130CAA0A01A7CDE5A2B4FEB8B311707.index) - code 3
```

This tells you that you are using an older version of XMLBeans than the one that compiled the schema jars. You can use older schemas with newer runtimes, but not the other way around

As of November 2015, Apache POI uses Apache XMLBeans 2.3 to build the schema jars, and ships 2.6 as the default runtime. That means that you need to use 2.3 or later at runtime

Based on the exception, it looks like you've got XMLBeans 2.2 in use. Remove / replace the old XMLBeans jar, so you have 2.3 or newer (ideally 2.6 which is the most recent), and things will start working

Note also that simply adding a newer XMLBeans jar to your classpath isn't enough - you need to remove the old one too. If you have old and new ones on the classpath, the old one will normally win!

Answer (score 0):

I think You have to use XSSFWorkbook  instead of Workbook read  read detail example at http://java67.blogspot.in/2014/09/how-to-read-write-xlsx-file-in-java-apache-poi-example.html

Comment: I've tried with both XSSF and HSSF in XSSF i got the same exception and in HSSF it say's "The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You need to call a different part of POI"